# Probability of an event not occuring in N trials

Tags: probability

In 2400 trials, there were 2 failures. I would like to show with high confidence that the underlying issue has been resolved that caused these two failures. To prove this, I would take N samples that show no failures. How many samples would I need to take to have 95% confidence that the issue is resolved, i.e. no failures occurred because of the fix in place and not just by chance?

I feel like this is a simple things to answer but its been a while since I've taken a statistics course.

P(X) = .05 = p^n 
     = log(.05) = n * log(p)
     n = 3,594 trails.

5% chance that in 3,594 trials all were passes based on the probability before a fix was put into place.

Does this look correct?

Comment: You haven't yet explained what "resolved" actually means.  Does it mean a failure is *impossible*?  If so, then no amount of sampling will demonstrate that.  Please, then, clarify this important point.

Comment: This would be correct if the *only two* possibilities are a 1/1200 chance of failure or a 0 chance of failure. However, reality will be more complex than that as the 1/1200 estimate is itself pretty uncertain, and 0 is probably too much to hope for.

Comment: Resolved would mean a failure is impossible, yes. I know no amount of sampling would _guarantee_ a failure couldn't happen, hence the 95% certain the issue has been resolved.

Comment: @PeterEllis any recommendation on how to be more precise in this estimation then? Increase trials without the fix in place, to be more certain of the failure probability?